# Keyword not supported: 'failover partner:sql-failover;initial catalog' in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008-r2, mirroring

We have a SQL Server configured for mirroring.  The initial server failed today and almost all our applications failed over correctly except for a VB.NET application.

When it starts up to set the connection string I get the following error:

```
"Keyword not supported: 'failover partner:sql-failover;initial catalog'."
```

Here is the code to connect:

```
    Dim sConnectionString As String
    Dim sServer As String

    Try
        'Always connect to production server to get startup environment variables
        If gbIsProduction Then
            If gsProductionServer = "" Then
                sServer = "PROD-SQL"
            Else : sServer = gsProductionServer
            End If
        Else : sServer = gsDevelopmentServer
        End If
        sConnectionString = "Data Source=" & sServer & ";Failover Partner:SQL-FAILOVER;Initial Catalog=*****;User ID=****;Password=******;"
        cnSystem.ConnectionString = sConnectionString
        cnSystem.Open()
        cmdSystem.Connection = cnSystem
    Catch ex As Exception
        RaiseError("", "modGeneral." & System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, Err.Number, Err.Description)
```

Any reason why?  I know Failover Partner is not supported in .NET 1.1 but I am using framework 3.5 SP1.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This part of the connection string is wrong

```
....;Failover Partner:SQL-FAILOVER;.....
```

should be

```
....;Failover Partner=SQL-FAILOVER;......
```

Comment: Yeah, I just saw that, thanks.  Now the connection string gets validated properly but it's not kicking over to the failover server.  Does it have to make a successful connection once to the initial server for failover to work?